# Why is Momo using a computer?

Tags: questionable-content

I'm referring to this edition of *Questionable Content*, the web-comic by Jeph Jaques.

Momo, with the pink hair, is an Anthro PC, a self-aware artificial intelligence in a robot body. The series refers to their access to the internet on a regular basis.

So why is Momo using a computer in this strip? Couldn't she do all the processing the computer does for herself?

[image: Questionable Content number 1471]

Comment: It might just be that she wants something to do? Instantly processing information you need can be usefull, but if you are alone on a friday night you just want to kill time browsing.

Comment: She’s playing WoW.

Comment: @iMerchant That could be an answer, if you can provide a source for it. It does, however, raise another question. Why does an AnthroPC need a PC to play World of Warcraft?

Comment: @AJFaraday - I have no source, hence typing a comment instead of answer. In fact, I’ve never even heard of this comic until I read your question. Actually, I was just trying to be funny. I suppose your question could apply to Data from Star Trek as well.

Comment: Perhaps she’s gold farming for Marigold :)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill possibly, the question is more why she’d need to use a PC. She is a PC.

Comment: I would just assume that AnthroPCs have “positronic brains” or some such. They’re not Intel-based and can’t run standard software.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill porting the software the anthro architecture or creating an emulator of an Intel shouldn't be that much of a challenge.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I feel like the presence of PT410x, who runs on Linux, is proof that Anthro-PCs run on Intel architecture. It's a real-world operating system which does, after all.

Comment: @AJFaraday: [Linux runs on a lot more than just Intel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures)

Comment: Self-preservation? I mean, if you were going to be on the Internet for an extended period of time, and could either connect your brain to it directly or use something as a buffer, which would you feel more comfortable doing? Occasional random access isn't the same as being connected for a long period of time, and runs less risk of being hacked. Out-of-universe: If you're just coming to the strip, someone sitting at a computer is obviously on the computer, and what's going on is more obvious to the reader who doesn't know everything yet. NOTE: all pure speculation, never seen the strip before.

Answer (score 18):

If you go forward a few days, you'll find that Momo is playing some WOW-like multi-user game (as seen in [strip 1473](http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=1473)).  Presumably, internalizing the game client and running it at AI-level direct-brain I/O speeds would be a breach of the game's terms (since that would effectively be "[botting](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/10459/bot-gaming)"), so Momo is simply competing fairly with the other (non-AI) players.

Comment: So my smartass comment earlier turned out to be correct? Whoa.

Comment: The strip does say she's playing WoW, but that's not the question. The question is about why a PC is playing WoW on another PC.

Comment: @AJFaraday That's the gist of my second sentence: all players are required to execute the (unmodded) game client externally in order to prevent AIs from gaining an insurmountable advantage over humans.  (This is not a canon explanation but is entirely reasonable based on real-life rules.)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for answering my own question here, I've loved the conversation around this issue. However, it was addressed some time later in a [recent strip](https://questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3954).

> Beepatrice: Anyway, let me show you your desk! You can use the external PC, or if you'd rather work plugged in, that's fine too.
>
> Rocco: I'll work externally. It's what I'm used to.

It appears that using a computer human-style is a matter of preference for robot AIs. They can be plugged in, or use Human Interface Devices.

[image: Full comic strip]

Answer (score 3):

Some androids in the QC universe try to emulate human behaviour as accurately as possible, and they can choose to either interface directly with computers or use an 'external' PC.

[image: Questionable Content issue 3954]

Apparently Momo chose for external interfacing in the strip you mention.

Answer (score 0):

She's using Marigold's account to play the game for Marigold. As she's an AndroPC she doesn't have this app on her.